# Tomcat persistent and user specific session counter

Tags: java, session, tomcat, counter

I need to make persistent and user specific session counter. I made this

```
package my.package;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static HashMap activeSessions;

    public SessionCounter() {
        //How to restore session count?
        activeSessions = new HashMap();
    }

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        String userName = session.getAttribute("username");
        Integer count = (Integer) activeSessions.get(userName);
        if (count != null) {
            activeSessions.put(userName, Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() + 1));
        } else {
            activeSessions.put(userName, new Integer(1));
        }
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        String userName = session.getAttribute("username");
        Integer count = (Integer) activeSessions.get(userName);
        if (count != null && count.intValue() > 0) {
            activeSessions.put(userName, Integer.valueOf(count.intValue() - 1));
        }

    }

    public static HashMap getActiveSessions() {
        return activeSessions;
    }
}
```

Session are active even after restart tomcat but session count stored in my activeSessions variable is lost. How can I restore the session count after restart?

Answer (score 0):

When Tomcat is shut down (i.e, by the shutdown script and not by killing the process) all sessions a serialized and restored when it is started the next time.

An HttpSessionListener will always be recreated, therefore your HashMap gets newly instantiated and the information is lost. You will have to write a model that implements serialiable, that holds your data, and store it to the disk when Tomcat is shutdown.

Comment: &| maybe a filter that tracks session and stores counts on DB?